# Recibir una imagen por JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api

tengo el siguiente problema;
tengo un servicio Rest con ASP.Net MVC y actualmente estoy recibiendo la imagen por base64 y termina dandome un json kilometrico para guardar, por lo que queria saber como recibir la informacion binaria (en lo posible lo guardaria en base de datos como varchar para poder hacer una transicion no tan abrupta) y de ahi tengo que recuperarlo nuevamente al binario para poder mostrarlo en la web/aplicacion que estoy desarrollando.
a lo que voy es que, como deberia recibir el valor? como blob? y como lo deberia guardar en la base de datos? (si no se puede guardarlo como varchar, lo podria guardar como otro valor mas compatible, puedo modificar la base de datos en caso de ser necesario)

Comment: Esta clase de preguntas siempre da para opiniones. Pero si es un archivo, no deberias transferirlo como archivo? el sistema optimiza esas transferencias mejor

Comment: no se pued recibir la informacion de un archivo binaria si estas enviando un json, quizas debas separar la funcionalidad, por un lado enviar datos con el json y otro servicio recibe el upload del archivo como parametro del action

Comment: Si no tienes problemas con el tamaño no importa que tu json sea kilométrico, yo he recibido PDFs por json en b64 sin problemas.

Comment: @shop350 es que ese es el problema, el json kilometrico, que genera que algunas imagenes no las pueda leer despues de la base de datos (porque no se si se truncan o que puede estar pasando de por medio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existen librerias que podrian ayudar como ser

[jQuery-File-Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload)

con esta podrias enviar datos y upload en la misma operacion

Analiza puntualmente

[How to submit additional form data](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/How-to-submit-additional-form-data)

veras como permite el upload y subir un json cuando usa

```
 $('#fileupload').fileupload({
     formData: {example: 'test'}
 });
```

ojo que el `formData` es el body que se recibira como post, lo que dice `test` que es el dato alli derias poner el json serializado que se enviara junto al file cuando se realice el upload

Answer (score 1):

Aqui hay dos preguntas como lo envias y como lo guardas!

La primera creo que te respondieron, con un plugin de Jquery, pero hasta con un simple formulario en HTML con el atributo *enctype= "multipart/form-data"* puedes enviar archivos (y el control html correcto el input tipo file) . Luego ya puedas dependiendo de la funcionalidad o la experiencia de usuario que requieras que pueda subir múltiples archivos con algún plugin de tu framework que estas utilizando para el front-end.

**Con respecto a si es un servicio Rest** y quieres mejorarlo al envio en base64 (sin cambiar gRPC, lo dejo para que lo investigues). Podrias utilizar [MessagePack](https://msgpack.org/) o [protobuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers). Dale una mirada pero es serializar estos datos para que "sea lo menos posible" al enviar. Recomendacion protobuf (tendrias que serializarlo en el cliente con esto, y en el servidor deserializarlo tambien con alguna libreria para .NET) . Ademas de esto de la serializacion del mensaje a enviar, tambien podrias mejorar el transporte o utilizando websockets, http2, etc).

**Con respecto a guardar en la DB**  Depende de que base de datos, hay formas diferentes de guardar blobs. Por ejemplo en SQL Server (las ultimas versiones)

- [VARBINAY(MAX)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/binary-and-varbinary-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
  Pero puedes agregar "caracteristicas" a estas tablas que tiene VARBINARY, porque tiene un limite que 2GB. Por ejemplo [FileStream](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/filestream-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15).
  Microsoft propopne que tus archivos blob son de mas de 1MB entonces utiliza [FileStream](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/filestream-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15). Dale una mirada porque esto guarda en disco los archivos (pero lo administra el motor SQL).

Ademas hay un tipo nuevo de tabla que se llama [FileTable](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/filetables-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)  (nuevo en el SQL 2012) que es tener ya una carpeta con subcarpetas que puedas guardar y recuperar datos incluso por fuera del SQL.

Dale una mirada a estos enlaces y mira cual te conviene.